# Mathematical Modelling of Wireless Power Transfer

Tags: modeling, electromagnetism, power-transmission, biomedical-engineering, radio

I am trying to understand the interaction between a transmitting antenna with a certain transmitting power (denoted PTX in the diagram) and how the radiation pattern of the TX antenna is affected by a RX antenna implanted inside the human body and by the human body itself. The purpose of this is to eventually be able to create a first-order analytical model for power density inside the human body.

[image: Basic System Configuration]
For this system, I am assuming that the dimensions of both antenna are known and that the electrical characteristics of the tissue layers are also known (i.e. permittivity and conductivity). As a simplification, each tissue layer is also assumed to have a fixed dimension (d1, d2 etc. as in the diagram).

I am looking for principles which I can use to mathematically describe the EM wave propagation through the human body, taking into account the effects of the human body and the RX antenna on the radiation pattern of the TX antenna.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. // When your wavelength is smaller than relevant dimensions inside a body, say in the cm OOM, i.e. using GHz frequencies, you have little to no diffraction. Then you can use the approach known from optics, where $r + t + a = 1$, all are complex numbers, denoting reflection, transmission, absorption. However, you may want to establish a reference, like a receiver outside the body. Effect will certainly depend on frequency i.e. wavelength, directions etc.

Comment: However, in the GHz range waves may not be able to penetrate the whole body.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757459/2451